# Why is uploading of file(s) failing in Apps?

Tags: 2sxc

I'm trying to create a simple App that contains a set of documents.  The Content-Type I'm having trouble with has 2 fields:
1. Title (String, default)
2. Docs (Hyperlink, library)

When trying to upload the documents I'm getting an error:

[IMAGE: The upload failed. The most likely cause is that the file you were trying to upload is bigger than the maximum upload size.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRuWk.png)

When I create Content, and not an App, following the same structure, the files upload without issue.

[IMAGE: Here you can see in simple content, the files have uploaded as expected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mi3xW.png)

Is there something that needs to be done differently in an App, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as you.  I tested with multiple version of 2sxc and the behavior persists.

There is an open issue ticket on their GitHub
https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/1431